# Delete a row from subreport in MS-Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to Delete a row from a subreport (my subreport used different columns values from different tables). But I've got a **Data type mismatch** error!

Below is the code I used:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM StateBudget " & " WHERE S_ID = " & _ 
                   DLookup("ID", "States", "State='" & _ 
                   Me.subformStateBudget.Form.Recordset.Fields("State") & "'")
```

I think *S_ID* is a text value, so how can I change DLookup value to string or text?

Comment: Is it a form, (sub)report, or both/all?

Comment: It's both. I have a Delete button to run above query.

Comment: So you have a form open and also have a report with a subreport open?

Comment: below answer solved the problem. Thank you @Gustav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the DLookUp value to a string, you need to pass it to SQL as a string (in quotes):

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM StateBudget " & " WHERE S_ID = """ & _ 
                   DLookup("ID", "States", "State='" & _ 
                   Me.subformStateBudget.Form.Recordset.Fields("State") & "'") & """"
```

Comment: It's Work perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: Then please mark it as the correct answer.